# Facebook Graph API v2.0 search posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get all user posts with status_type="mobile_status_update" or status_type="added_photos" but it seems API 2.0 doesn't support search method anymore,

Is there a way to achieve my goal? or do I need to get all posts and check those status_type on my loop?

this is what I have done so far on graph api explorer

http://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me/posts?fields=id,name,message,type,status_type&limit=100&status_type=added_photos

I don't want to use API v1.0, because I have read that facebook will deprecate it on 2015

Comment: you will also have a hard time getting the posts like that - read_stream will not get approved unless you are using it for a platform without a native facebook experience (a tv, for example).

Comment: not sure what you mean  by that, I test that api request on graph api explorer, I can search query on api explorer if I used v1.0 but not in v2.0, I can retrieve all posts easily but I can't get those posts with status_type is mobile_status_update or added_photos